# Make mathematical equation from 3 lists python

Tags: python, list, math, equation

So, i have 3 lists of items. One where the price is stored, one where quantity is stored and one where column numbers are stored. They all have the exact same numbers of elements, and that number is x. I need to do this:

```
finalprice = quantityofx1 * priceofx1 + quantityofx2 * priceofx2 + quantityofxn * priceofxn
```

How to do this?

Comment: You need to do loops :)

Comment: can you show me how? :)

Comment: Of course. I'll write a example commenting. second.

Comment: http://repl.it/9Hl something like this

Comment: http://repl.it/9Hl/1 - the same, using dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 0
while i < x:
    finalprice = list_number_1[i] * list_number_2[i]
    i += 1
```

i is list index. while i < x means, that loop will keep going until i will no longer be less than x 
list_number_1[i] * list_number_2[i] means:
"i" element of first list multiple by "i" element of second list

Comment: Don't you mean finalprice += ... instead of finalprice= ...?

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you have two lists, one with prices and another with quantities. Our first step is to find the length of one of these lists for the purpose of looping. From there, we use the indices in the for loop to create subtotals. At the end, we simply find the sum of the subtotals.

```
prices = [] # list of prices
amount = [] # list of quantities
totals = [] # empty list

# populate subtotals

for i in range(len(prices)):
    subtotal = prices[i] * amount[i]
    totals.append(subtotal)

print sum(totals) # print entire total
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of an explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
assert len(prices) == len(quantities)
```

length of the prices list and the quantities list should equal x

```
finalprice = 0
for i in range(len(prices)): 
    finalprice += prices[i] * quantities[i]
print finalprice
```